# How to cross-compile open-zwave library for asus rt-n16?

Tags: compiling, compilation-target

Open-zwave lib link: http://code.google.com/p/open-zwave/source/browse/

Toolchain used: http://code.google.com/p/wl500g/downloads/list?can=3&q=hndtools-mipsel-uclibc-4.4.6-K26

Asus RT-N16 running on wl500g firmware: http://code.google.com/p/wl500g/

I've tried to do the following:

1. added toolchain path: `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/hndtools-mipsel-uclibc-4.4.6-K26/bin/`
2. сhecked out all needed files: `svn checkout http://open-zwave.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ open-zwave`
3. added `CROSS_COMPILE = mipsel-linux-` to */open-zwave/cpp/build/linux/Makefile*
4. tried to make: `~/open-zwave/cpp/build/linux$ make`
5. got error: `../../hidapi/linux/hid.c:40:26: error: linux/hidraw.h: No such file or directory`
6. replaced *gcc* with *mipsel-linux-gcc*, *g++* with *mipsel-linux-g++* at */home/user/open-zwave/cpp/hidapi/linux/Makefile*
7. tried to make HIDAPI: ~/open-zwave/cpp/hidapi/linux$ make
8. got another error: `hid-libusb.c:44:19: error: iconv.h: No such file or directory`

How to cross-compile that?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!